# Are Git or SVN coming with a memory footprint?

Tags: svn, git

If you install GIT or SVN (Server Repo) on Linux, will it run any permanent processes i.e. will it leave a permanent memory footprint on my Linux server?

I'm on a server where keeping down memory usage is of the essence.

Comment: do you know of any programmer who doesn't use version controls. get a life.

Comment: @Beska: clever. I give you that. but seriously, why are so many so hard on someone who needs help. There's obviously a bunch of ppl out there who knew the answer to this semi-programming-related question.

If stackoverflow becomes some sort of elitist place where only this but not that can be discussed, then it's on its way out. Think about it.

Comment: Would this be a central store or just a client?

Comment: @Matthew Whited: well, in general I like to have a central repo where I know it won't disappear if I accidently set the building on fire and lose the hand held, laptop or home server. So central store is a must, even though I guess GIT really has no "central", it's simply where you did push or pull the latest.

Comment: Currently most svn questions are on SO, not SF, so I'd consider this relevant.

Comment: @Adergaard: not trying to be hard on you...nor make make SO an elitist place.  Rather I'm trying to improve both SO and SF.  The question itself is a good one...one that I'm guessing will probably be useful to several people.  But, despite being answerable by several people here, it isn't actually directly related to the problems of programming...while it is *very* directly related to the issues that are handled by ServerFault.  If I were searching for this type of thing in general, SF is where I would go...so I think that's where the question should be.

Comment: @Ether: Just because other questions are in the wrong spot, doesn't mean this one should be.  I agree that having all the questions in the same spot would be ideal...but I think the other ones should go, too.  However, the underlying point is well taken...that the existence of the majority of these questions on SO, rather than SF, implies that I may well be in the minority in my opinion about which site is better suited to these questions.

Comment: @Beska: cool. point taken. but consider this, of all my friends there are 100% who knows of SO. There are 0% who knows of SF. There may be some other place where it would fit even better. So why not post there? Well I actually wanted the question answered by this crowd. Not in a week by some crowd who knows how to install Debian Lenny and probably considers Debian Etch to forward thinking and sticking with Debian 2.0.... Drifting a bit off the target here my point is: right now SO is the cat's pyjamas, and that's the crowd I want to turn to when I have a question to get good, fast answers.

Answer (score 3):

Subversion will require you to run either the svnserve daemon or mod_webdav in Apache to access your repositories.  If you are looking to keep things to a minimum, you can set up svnserve to run as an inetd service (this is how I run a Subversion server on a little linux laptop in the basement) or using svn+ssh.  Note that in all cases, a daemon is required to accept the incoming request, but you maybe able to piggyback on an existing service.

GIT can be used without a daemon of any kind, if you simply plan to use file sharing to synchronize your repositories.  This isn't an ideal setup for a large development group, but it is workable if you are really constrained.

If one of these sounds better than the other, let me know and I can elaborate further.

Comment: Subversion can run in a serverless mode like git does, look at svn+ssh  repo designations.

Comment: Subversion doesn't require daemon if you go svn+ssh

Answer (score 3):

Don't know for git, but for svn: you have multiple options.

If you use svnserve yes, it will have a running process. 
If you use svn+ssh protocol the svn process will only get created when needed, and not leave a permanent process running.
If you already have an apache httpd running you can also let that one deliver svn content, in which case you have obviously the apache footprint.

Comment: With git you have the same mode as svn+ssh, it works basically the same using the opened ssh connection to pipe the protocol.

Comment: In this case, SVN doesn't need a resident process, but a daemon is still required (sshd) to accept the request.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, subversion allows you to run without memory footprint, through ssh, will execute svnserve only for the moment you are commiting.

Comment: It sounds like the server is very constrained...  I didn't want to assume sshd was running.  If it isn't that will have to be added, in which case, a daemon is required to access SVN.

Comment: If you can't run sshd then you have a really tiny machine, and if that's the case, surely svnserve or git will blow the doors off.